# Pygtk notes links

Tags: python, pygtk

if any of you are familiar with PyGTK links for beginners to grasp within a week, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html

Comment: GTK, while open source makes it awesome, is a pita... I wrote a whole program just to learn pygtk and I **STILL** don't have a clue why it does what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are handy links to have open when programming with pygtk:

**GTK 2**

PyGTK 2.x Reference Manual:  http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/

PyGTK Tutorial by Andrew Steele:  http://learngtk.org/tutorials/pygtk-tutorial/

PyGTK FAQ:  http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=index

**GTK 3**

Python GI API Reference  http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0

The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial  http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial by Andrew Steele http://learngtk.org/tutorials/python_gtk3_tutorial/html/

Answer (score 1):

Micah Carrick's tutorial: http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: I've love to +1 this since I wrote it, but, it is getting a bit out of date. I'm working on a new one for GTK+3 with Python and GObject introspection... but... who knows when I'll have time to finish that.